# How to pass value to a function in flask?

Tags: python, flask

Probably it is something trivial but I am totally new to flask and I got stacked.
I want to make a function that takes a name from the URL and if the name exists in a list, it will print the details of this person.
I have followed the steps of a tutorial and it works fine for the tutorial's functions, but not for mine.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, Flask!"


@app.route("/hello/<name>")
def hello_there(name):
    now = datetime.now()
    formatted_now = now.strftime("%A, %d %B, %Y at %X")

    # Filter the name argument to letters only using regular expressions. URL arguments
    # can contain arbitrary text, so we restrict it to safe characters only.
    match_object = re.match("[a-zA-Z]+", name)

    if match_object:
        clean_name = match_object.group(0)
    else:
        clean_name = "Friend"

    content = "Hello there, " + clean_name + "! It's " + formatted_now
    return content

def search(name):
    people = [
{'firstName': "Tom",'lastName':'Beker', 'age': 10, 'profession':'cat'},
{'firstName': "Jerry",'lastName':'Taylor', 'age': 15, 'profession':'mouse'},
{'firstName': "Lucky",'lastName':'Luke', 'age': 22, 'profession':'cowboy'},
{'firstName': "Joe",'lastName':'Dalton', 'age': 30, 'profession':'bandit'},
{'firstName': "Sam",'lastName':'Dragon', 'age': 10, 'profession':'superHero'}
]
    return [element for element in people if element['lastName'] == name]
```

When it runs without a name in the URL, the home() runs fine.
The hello_there() also when I am providing the name, but the search() doesn't.

Is it something that I'm missing?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You don't have a `route` decorator for `search`.

Comment: Yes, you are right!
I thought that one route decorator was enough.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the `@app.route` decorator for the search function
You may want to try something like this

```
@app.route("/search/<name>")
def search(name):
    people = [
        {'firstName': "Tom",'lastName':'Beker', 'age': 10, 'profession':'cat'},
        {'firstName': "Jerry",'lastName':'Taylor', 'age': 15, 'profession':'mouse'},
        {'firstName': "Lucky",'lastName':'Luke', 'age': 22, 'profession':'cowboy'},
        {'firstName': "Joe",'lastName':'Dalton', 'age': 30, 'profession':'bandit'},
        {'firstName': "Sam",'lastName':'Dragon', 'age': 10, 'profession':'superHero'}
    ]
    return [element for element in people if element['lastName'] == name]
```

then using a `GET /search/sample_name` you'll get your result

Comment: Thank you very much!
I just added the ```@app.route("/search/<name>")``` and it worked.
Where should I use the ```GET /search/sample_name``` ?

Comment: You do that when making an API call. Example curl http://localhost:4000/search/Luke